# Why does Telegram give me an empty POST request on the webhook?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I followed these steps:

1. Registered a bot with BotFather.
2. Send a post request for the webhook ([https://api.telegram.org/bot[BOTID]/setWebhook](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BBOTID%5D/setWebhook)) with the URL being https://example.com/myscript.php
3. Double check with getWebhookInfo and it showed it is correctly registered.
4. When I send a message to the bot, the script is being called but with an empty POST payload. In the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) they say they would send an HTTPS POST request to the specified url, containing a JSON-serialized Update.

Does anyone else has this issue and perhaps know a way to resolve this?

My php script to log:

```php
    $file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/telegram-log.txt';
    $entry = (object)array();
    $entry->date = date("r");
    $entry->GET = $_GET;
    $entry->POST = $_POST;
    $entry->REQUEST = $_REQUEST;
    $entry->HTTP_USER_AGENT = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $entry->REMOTE_ADDR = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($entry) . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Response:

```
{"date":"Thu, 17 Jun 2021 13:42:49 +0200","GET":[],"POST":[],"REQUEST":[],"HTTP_USER_AGENT":null,"REMOTE_ADDR":"91.108.6.133"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$content = file_get_contents("php://input")` to receive updates.

Telegram's response is of content-type `application/json`.

`$_POST` will only work when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.